# Javascript only executing one window.onload trigger on html <input> source

Tags: javascript, html

Im currently writing a program with three images as input triggers when clicked on, when they are clicked on a program in javascript executes a function, however only one picture when clicked is executing the javascript correctly. It is the last one in the script. I have been working on this for 5 hours now with no success. Would be amazing if someone could help me out. Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>TIC TAC TOE</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="TTTcss.css"></head>

<body>
  <div class="body">
    <input type="image" src="/ProjectTTT/PicturesTTT/Papa.jpg" name="saveForm" class="papier" id="papier">
    <input type="image" src="/ProjectTTT/PicturesTTT/ScissorsTTT.jpeg" name="saveForm" class="schere" id="schere">
    <input type="image" src="/ProjectTTT/PicturesTTT/StoneTTT.jpeg" name="saveForm" class="stein" id="stein">
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

```
window.onload = function() {

  document.getElementById("papier").onclick = function() {
    var getNumba = function(start, range) {
      var getRandom = Math.floor(((Math.random() * range) + start));
      while (getRandom > range) {
        var getRandom = Math.floor(((Math.random() * range) + start));
      }
      return getRandom;
    }
    var RPS = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];

    var ComputerSelection = RPS[getNumba(0, 3)];
    var PlayerSelection1 = ("paper");
    console.log(ComputerSelection);
    var PlayerSelection = PlayerSelection1.toLowerCase();

    if (PlayerSelection == ComputerSelection) {
      alert("draw");
      console.log("draw");

    } else if (ComputerSelection == "rock")

    {
      alert("you won");
      console.log("won");
    } else if (ComputerSelection == "scissors")

    {
      alert("you lose");
      console.log("lose");
    }
  }
};

window.onload = function() {

  document.getElementById("schere").onclick = function() {
    var getNumba = function(start, range) {
      var getRandom = Math.floor(((Math.random() * range) + start));
      while (getRandom > range) {
        var getRandom = Math.floor(((Math.random() * range) + start));
      }
      return getRandom;
    };

    var RPS = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];

    var ComputerSelection = RPS[getNumba(0, 3)];
    var PlayerSelection1 = ("scissors");
    console.log(ComputerSelection);
    var PlayerSelection = PlayerSelection1.toLowerCase();

    if (PlayerSelection == ComputerSelection) {
      alert("draw");
      console.log("draw");

    } else if (ComputerSelection == "paper") {
      alert("win");
      console.log("win");
    } else if (ComputerSelection == "rock")

    {
      alert("lose");
      console.log("lose");
    }



  }
};



window.onload = function() {

  document.getElementById("papier").onclick = function() {
    var getNumba = function(start, range) {
      var getRandom = Math.floor(((Math.random() * range) + start));
      while (getRandom > range) {
        var getRandom = Math.floor(((Math.random() * range) + start));
      }
      return getRandom;
    }

    var RPS = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];

    var ComputerSelection = RPS[getNumba(0, 3)];
    var PlayerSelection1 = ("paper");
    console.log(ComputerSelection);
    var PlayerSelection = PlayerSelection1.toLowerCase();

    if (PlayerSelection == ComputerSelection) {
      alert("draw");
      console.log("draw");

    } else if (ComputerSelection == "scissors")

    {
      alert("you won");
      console.log("won");
    } else if (ComputerSelection == "paper")

    {
      alert("you lose");
      console.log("lose");
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You're setting the `window.onload` to the last function. This is why it's the only one that works. What you should do instead is, have one `window.onload = function [...]` and put everything in there.

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason you can't place all that code in a single function, use `addEventListener` instead.

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
  // do something ...
});
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
  // do something else ...
});
```